# Amazon Lex not recognize voice

Tags: react-native, bots, voice, aws-amplify, amazon-lex

I am using aws-amplify (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/interactions#using-with-react) library with react-native to develop a voice chat bot,it's working fine with text chat but when I send a voice input to the bot it doesn't work.Every time I am getting a reply "Speak into the mic" and a error "5/Client side error".

I have installed all the peer dependencies require for the  voice interaction as describe in the doc, but still I am not getting the proper reply.

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
      identityPoolId: 'us-east-1:e058a291-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
      region: 'us-east-1'
    },
    Interactions: {
      bots: {
        "OrderFlowers": {
          "name": "OrderFlowers",
          "alias": "$LATEST",
          "region": "us-east-1",
          "userId": "0f1a42ce-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
        },
      }
    }
  });


export default class Home extends Component {

    state = {
        botName: 'OrderFlowers',
        welcomeMessage: 'Welcome, what would you like to do today?',
      };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleComplete = this.handleComplete.bind(this);

    }

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        header:null

    });

    handleComplete(err, confirmation) {
        if (err) {
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Bot conversation failed', [{ text: 'OK' }]);
          return;
        }

        Alert.alert('Done', JSON.stringify(confirmation, null, 2), [{ text: 'OK' }]);

        this.setState({
            botName: 'OrderFlowers',
        });

        return 'Flower Ordered Successfully..!! THANK YOU';
      }


    render() {
        const { botName, showChatBot, welcomeMessage } = this.state;

        return (

               <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
               <ChatBot
                botName={botName}
                welcomeMessage={welcomeMessage}
                onComplete={this.handleComplete}
                clearOnComplete={true}
                styles={StyleSheet.create({
                    itemMe: {
                    color: 'red'
                    }
                })}
                voiceEnabled={true}
                voiceLibs={voiceLibs}
                conversationModeOn={true}
               />
           </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, please help me out facing exactly same issue.....was you able to fix it...please help....

Comment: hello, please help me out on this, were you able to fix this issue?